# Access to folder rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have folder on root of my rails project, which name is 'uploads'
Is there any way to access of files which it include from inside? Like from 'public' folder

How i get this it should be done with nginx conf, but i dod not get way how to get this work

My config file

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/toropanov/shared/tmp/sockets/toropanov-      puma.sock;
}

server {
 listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;

  root /home/deploy/apps/toropanov/current/public;
  access_log /home/deploy/apps/toropanov/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/apps/toropanov/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a location to your server block in your .conf file (typically something like `/etc/nginx/conf.d/my_app.conf`)

```
server {
  listen 80;

  # existing config goes here...

  # allow access to uploads folder
  location /uploads {
    alias /path/to/app/uploads;
  }
}
```